# Armature awkwardly twisting mesh no matter how many different things I try

Tags: mesh, armature

I was able to get each individual area of vertices set correctly to each bone but had to do that manually because automatic weights wouldnt work. Once I finally got it done manually I had the issue of other bones having weights and the movement was lagged and I figured that out. But now its like no matter what I do I cannot get this posing to smooth out. The mesh is 1.5 meters tall. Any ideas? Here are the pictures of what I'm talking about. IT's an arm on a short stubby guy. That's the shoulder.

[image]

[image]

Full size links:
https://ibb.co/DK0Dkkm
https://ibb.co/PmFRRX5

Comment: you tried to use merge by distance and then apply bone -> parent automatic weight?

Comment: I did yeah. Still had the same issue